# .where returning nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  def new
    @host = Host.find(params[:id])
    @lastreview = Review.where("user_id = ? AND host_id = ?", current_user[:id], @host.id)
    if @lastreview == nil
        @review = Review.new
    else
        redirect_to @host, notice: "You already posted a review for this host!"
    end
  end
```

For some reason it is not returning nil even though their are no reviews? Am I misunderstanding the usage?

Comment: where and why do you expect to return nil?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is if a review doesn't exist where that user had already made one under that host ID it would allow you to review that host. I'm figured if it wasn't able to find anything @lastreview would be returned as nil but, Perhaps I am mistaking.

Comment: I guess you meant to evaluate to `nil`, not necessarily return `nil`

Comment: `Review.where("user_id = ? AND host_id = ?", current_user[:id], @host.id).first` would return `nil` in case of no result. but without `.first`, you will get an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` returns an array - if there are no reviews in your table that match your conditions, the array that it returns will be empty, but it will never be nil.

Try this instead:

```
if @lastreview.empty?
    @review = Review.new
else
    redirect_to @host, notice: "You already posted a review for this host!"
end
```

Comment: That did it. I forgot about empty?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need the last records, you can use [`exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F):

> Returns `true` if a record exists in the table that matches the id or conditions given, or `false` otherwise.

This should work (Rails can handle the `_id` suffixes if everything is set up correctly):

```
def new
  @host = Host.find(params[:id])
  if Review.exists?(user: current_user, host: @host)
    @review = Review.new
  else
    redirect_to @host, notice: "You already posted a review for this host!"
  end
end
```